# How do I get the number of points in the json file to use in a for loop in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have this json file:

```
[
  { "results": 
    { "points": 
      [ 
        { "name" : "s1"  } , 
        { "name" : "s2"  } , 
        { "name" : "j1"  } , 
        { "name" : "n1"  }
      ] 
    } 
  } 
]
```

And this python code to read it:

```
import json

with open('test.json') as json_file:
  data = json.load(json_file)
json_file.close()

for i in len(data[0]["results"]["points"]):
  print(data[0]["results"]["points"][i]["name"],': ')
```

Which fails with the len statement.  Is this what I should be using, or something else?

Comment: Do you mean nodes or points?

Comment: sorry edit issue, fixed

Comment: Probably you want "range(len(...))" instead of "len(...)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, you usually don't think your loop in term of indices. But you loop over your items directly

```
import json
from pathlib import Path

data = json.loads(Path("test.json").read_text())

for point in data[0]["results"]["points"] :
    print(point)
```

If you still want the indices use enumerate()

```
for n, point in enumerate(data[0]["results"]["points"]) :
    print(n, point)
```

By the way, if you use the context manager `with`, you don't need to explicitly close your file, that's what the context manager does for you.

Answer (score 1):

The error you got:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [8], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 for i in len(data[0]["results"]["points"]):
      2   print(data[0]["results"]["points"][i]["name"],': ')

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

is telling you that `for i in X` where `X` in this case an int, is not iterable. Try this and you get the same error: `for i in 4`. The fix is to enclose the `len()` phrase with `range()`:

```py
for i in range(len(data[0]["results"]["points"])):
  print(data[0]["results"]["points"][i]["name"],': ')
```

That code works, but it is messy. A cleaner, more Pythonic version is:

```py
for point in data[0]["results"]["points"]:
    print(point["name"], ":")
```

which produces the same output.